# MVC: Problems to pass currency in decimal parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying pass a currency value to a decimal property, but the MVC removes the ",". I tried with ".", but the MVC removes too.

```
public ActionResult MyAction(decimal value)
{
}
```

I'm sending the ajax request to the following URL:

> /MyAction?value=1000,35

But when I send the request, I received the 100035 value. Why?

Comment: See http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/

Comment: that looks like a problem related to culture parameters. What's the format setting on your machine? I have just tested that: passing a decimal to an action and it works with "."

Comment: @haim770 This helped me to solve my problem, thanks a lot!! :D

Comment: You can post (as an answer) what you've changed to make it work, so other people can benefit from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve my problem, I used this article:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/

I created one DecimalModelBinder like the article shows

Another thing that I did is converting the decimal to string before to send to action:

```
var url = string.Format("/MyAction?value={0}", decimalValue);
```