# Ajax method not hitting controller when decimal

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add like a timeregistration functionality in my web application. The user has a form where he can select the project he worked on, and then enter the amount of hours spend working on that project.

Now this works fine, untill you start adding half hours. like 5.5.
For some reason, the ajax doesn't hit the controller. When I console.log the response it says that the parameter 'hours' can not be empty and should be set as optional. So I presume for some reason, it doesn't take my variable if it's a decimal.

```
function AddTimeReg() {
...
 var hours;
    var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
    if (language === "en-US"){
         hours = $("#Hours").val().trim().replace(",", ".");
    }
    else{
         hours = $("#Hours").val().trim().replace(".", ",");
    }
   ...
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: appPath + '/TimeReg/ShopDoc',
            data: {
                regDate: date, salesOrder: salesorder, shopDoc: shopdoc, startTime: convertedStartTime, endTime: convertedEndTime,
                hours: hours, info: info, timeRegLineNr: timeRegLineNr
            },
...
}
```

And the controller:

```
public ActionResult ShopDoc(DateTime regDate, string salesOrder, string shopDoc, string startTime, string endTime, decimal hours, string info, int timeRegLineNr)
  {
      ... 
  }
```

So, for some reason: it works fine with hours like 5, 2 or 8.. but the controller doesn't get hit by breakpoint if i.e. we type 5.5 or 2,5.

Edit: Not a duplicate from the link. In the link we're talking about giving the parameter in the url as actionresult and the issue there is in c# while here, I believe there is something missing within the JS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC: Problems to pass currency in decimal parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480754/mvc-problems-to-pass-currency-in-decimal-parameter)

Comment: @kalyfe how is that relevant exactly? This is more a JS issue than C# I believe.

Comment: It looks like the problem is with the MVC controller, specifically with the parameter ´hours´ - parsing the decimal is dependend on the culture.

Comment: And how can your link make sure to fix this as we don't even hit the controller in the first place?

Comment: You are right, you are submitting ´hours´ as a string. You can parse it into a number in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're sending a decimal type to begin with... as your code stands, it's currently sending a string instead of a decimal...

Use `parseFloat()` on your `hours` property so that it gets serialized properly into JSON when it's being sent to your controller.

---

Edit:

It's a binding issue...

We need to extract the parameters on your controller to a model

```
public class ShopDocModel
{
    public DateTime regDate   {get;set;} 
    public string salesOrder  {get;set;}
    public string shopDoc     {get;set;}
    public string startTime   {get;set;}
    public string endTime     {get;set;}
    public decimal hours      {get;set;}
    public string info        {get;set;}
    public int timeRegLineNr { get; set; }
}
```

and then reference that in the controller parameter

```
public ActionResult ShopDoc(ShopDocModel model)
```

That should resolve your issue

---

EDIT

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: appPath + '/TimeReg/ShopDoc',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            regDate: date, salesOrder: salesorder, shopDoc: shopdoc, startTime: convertedStartTime, endTime: convertedEndTime,
            hours: hours, info: info, timeRegLineNr: timeRegLineNr
        }),
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

Comment: Have you tried it prior to changing the culture settings... also can you do me a favour and install Fiddler...

Fiddler is a reverse proxy which makes it a lot more easier to debug stuff like this. It will show exactly whatever it is that you're sending out and what the response is from the server.

Comment: Thanks I never heard of that tool before. 
https://i.imgur.com/PtnZyAt.png  https://i.imgur.com/dQQfur5.png

Comment: @Катерина updated, let me know if that makes a difference

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, hours is now 0 when passing into the controller. edit: I did this just before the ajax method:   var x = parseFloat(hours);

Comment: Still the same, works with i.e. 5. but not with 5.5. when hitting a decimal, the controller takes it as 0.

Comment: Would you be able to post the fiddler shots again please but this time just the RAW tab, also make sure the js isnt being cached

Comment: The request seems fine, but inside the controller hours is 0 :( https://imgur.com/zVb3uWr

Comment: are you absolutely positive? temporarily change the controller action to return this...             `return this.Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and show me the response, the `model` should be referrencing the input argument `ActionResult ShopDoc(ShopDocModel model)`

Comment: I can't figure it out mate, when I try the above in a clean solution, I can't reproduce your problem.

Is there any settings you've used which might be messing with the results? such as custom bindings etc... and is it restricted to just decimal, what happens if you use double, (trying to figure out if the issue is only with the decimal type)

Comment: Same here, really no clue what's happening. I'll try to change it to double and play around, thanks for the help though! really much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your source code.

It worked well with "2.5" or 2.5 value in hours.

If you put "2,5" MVC model binder can't cast to decimal. You need change your script.

```
if (language === "en-US"){
         hours = $("#Hours").val().trim().replace(",", ".");
    }
    else{
         hours = $("#Hours").val().trim().replace(".", ",");
    }
```

to

```
hours = $("#Hours").val().trim().replace(",", ".");
```

Update code reproduce:

You can create another controller to reproduce it.
Also you should create object and console log to see real data before ajax call:

```
var form = {
                regDate: date, salesOrder: salesorder, shopDoc: shopdoc, startTime: convertedStartTime, endTime: convertedEndTime,
                hours: hours, info: info, timeRegLineNr: timeRegLineNr
            }
console.log(form);
```

public class HomeController : Controller
{

```
 public ActionResult ShopDoc(DateTime regDate, string salesOrder, string shopDoc, string startTime, string endTime, decimal hours, string info, int timeRegLineNr)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

}

Index.cshtml

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/Home/ShopDoc',
        data: {
            regDate: '2019-11-11',
            salesOrder: "1",
            shopDoc: "1",
            startTime: '2019/11/11',
            endTime: '2019/11/11',
            hours: "2.5",
            info: "1",
            timeRegLineNr: 1
        }, success: function (result) {

        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {

        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Tried it but unfortunately didn't change anything. Also when typing 2.5 :(

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the 'hours' value to number using:

```
hours = Number(hours).toFixed(2);
```

Then use JSON.stringify over the 'data'. Something like this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
            regDate: date, salesOrder: salesorder, shopDoc: shopdoc, startTime: convertedStartTime, endTime: convertedEndTime,
            hours: hours, info: info, timeRegLineNr: timeRegLineNr
})
```

Comment: `toFixed()` returns a string and not a number. And the reason is, that usually no number exists that reflects the result of `toFixed()` exactly.